# PHP session_destroy() not called with default SESSION handler by garbage collector?

Tags: php, session, garbage-collection, destroy

Is there any way to ensure that default PHP SESSION garbage collector will call some function on destroying expired session?

From my experience, default PHP garbage collector does not call any callback function on destroying the session.

I guess, the only way would be to define custom session handlers for all 5 operations - open, close, destroy, .. ? (redundant code for me)

The reason is, that I need to adjust counter for active sessions.

Perfect solution would be e.g. if it would be possible to register something like session_register_destroy(function) - but I am not sure if this is possible.

Thank you.

Comment: What about getting a count of active sessions? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17259650/368406

Comment: If you are using the session file handler then counting active sessions will involve enumerating the session save path directory. This is going to be a relatively slow operation because it goes to the disk and depending on the number of active sessions it might be quite the holdup. Have you thought about this?

Comment: Yes, i am using standard file storage. I want to avoid scanning session save_path (e.g. with glob(*.*)) because 1/ it is expensive operation 2/ I must only count sessions granted to human users, because robots (identified via http client signature) are always granted free for indexing the site. Therefore simple directory scan is not an option. So it looks like implementing simple session counter is not that simple, huh? :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no callback because of the way the standard file handler works.

Sessions are stored in files and PHP checks every now and then if there this file was not touched for more then 25 minutes (or actually `session.gc_maxlifetime` seconds)

If the file was not touched, it's deleted.
This garbage collection happens on every 100th request from clients, 
therefore if you server experienced no request for few hours, session files will continue to exist.

In your case you can count sessions separately, let's say via `apc` every time , or just count the amount of files newer then 25 minutes ago in the session directory.

Comment: Actually it is every 24 minutes (1440 secs by default). I am using Opcache, not APC. Sometime cache is completely turned off (in development).

Comment: apc was just a suggestion where you can store the count of active sessions. You can do this as well in a database or literally count the files on disk with `find` that were `mitem`ed later then 24 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I guess I'm little confused on what your trying to accomplish.

I believe you can do what you want by wrapping PHP session logic in a class and then use `__destruct()` method when the object gets destroyed or cleaned up.

```
<?
class Session
{
    public function __construct() {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION = array();
    }

    public function set($key, $value) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function get($key) {
        return $_SESSION[$key];
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        // Destroy browser session cookies
        if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
            $params = session_get_cookie_params();
            setcookie(
                session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
                $params["path"], $params["domain"],
                $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
            );
        }
        session_destroy();
    }
}

$session = Session();
$session->set('foo', 'bar');
echo $session->get('foo');
// Destory Session
unset($session);

?>
```

Comment: Thanx, I found out that implementing custom session handlers is the only way to have full control over garbage collector callback. Here are few good examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php.