# Live count of users on website which updates html

Tags: php, html, database

hi i have made a site and was wondering if i can put a count of how many people are on the site. not have been on but how many are on at that time. like a live count which updates if someone exits. if i can use php with a database to do that it would be awesome. i have no good experience with this sort of stuff but will love to have this on My Site.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am new to this and trying to find a path to completing the result @Nehal I want a number on the site that tells me how many are on the site at that time. A so as people go on and of my website the number will increase or decrease. But I want to access that number for one specific page on another page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that with session. hope this thread may helps you.

[Finding total number of active sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259212/finding-total-number-of-active-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to find an app online, I have previously made hit counters myself so I cannot make a suggestion as to what apps work well however I'm sure if you did a quick google search you'd find the results. To put you in the right direction I have found one online which seems like it might be a good option. Hope this helps.

Online app - http://www.freecounterstat.com/

Comment: He isn't asking for third-party solutions and here at SO, people seek help when they need assistance in writing their own code.